# Pattern matching multiple symbols names and powers

Tags: pattern-matching

Seemingly a relatively simple problem, I can't seem to find a solution...

I want to build a pattern that will match any symbol whose name starts with V, and is elevated at any power. Something on the line of:

```
MatchQ[#1, (V1 | V2 | V3)^_.] & /@ {V1, V1^2, V2}
```

That returns true for each of the entries. I haven't found a way to put constrains on the symbol name, if not by using `SymbolName[]` and working with string patterns:

```
MatchQ[#1, (_)?(StringMatchQ[SymbolName[#1], "V" ~~ __] &)^_.] & /@ {V1, V1^2, V2}
```

However, it doesn't look exactly beautiful... (only to me?) :-)
Is there a more compact and elegant way of putting constraints on a symbol name? I'm feeling like I'm totally missing a very obvious function that would do that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that if you want to match a Symbol by its constituent characters that you do need to use string patterns, therefore your solution is reasonable.  I recommend a variation:

```
p2 = s_Symbol^_. /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], "V*"]
```

`s_Symbol` makes sure that the expression that is passed to `SymbolName` is actually a Symbol.  I also find it somewhat more readable.  Test:

```
MatchQ[p2] /@ {V1, V1^2, V2, x^2, y}   (* v10 operator form syntax *)
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, False, False}
> ```

The use of [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) rather than [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) makes it easier if you may be working with held expressions and need to add [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
p3 = s_Symbol^_. /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s], "V*"]
```

This allows:

```
V1 = "Fail!";
Cases[Hold[V1, V1^2, V2, x^2, y], x : p2 :> Hold[x]]
V1 =.;
```

> ```
> {Hold[V1], Hold[V1^2], Hold[V2]}
> ```

To make the code a bit prettier consider an abstraction such as:

```
symPat = s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s], #] &;
```

Then simply:

```
Cases[{V1, V1^2, V2, x^2, y}, symPat["V*"]^_.]
```

> ```
> {V1, V1^2, V2}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, not only for he answer to the point, but for the additional info as well.

Comment: Just for the sake of sharing, what drew me off was the (semi-)unconscious and naive belief that by writing 'MatcQ[V1, V1]' (that I never really wrote) I was comparing the names of the symbols. Thus my reasoning was: if I can compare entire names, and "any" by using `_` (sort of * for symbol names), then there musts be a syntax to compare only part of the name (eventually completed by wildcards). Now I realize that 'MatchQ' compares the content of the symbols, hence the need to use `SymbolName` if you want to put constraints on the name... probably this was very clear to everyone except me! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mr. Wizard for the excellent answer above.  I just came across this post in search for an answer to a similar but not-quite-identical problem.

FWIW, here is my take on the answer posted.  My main use-case for it is filtering rules in long sets of rules, e.g. `AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationCell[]`:

```
StringRepresentationContainsQ[searchFor_String, 
  ignoreCase : _?(BooleanQ) : True] :=
 Function[searchIn,
  StringContainsQ[searchFor, IgnoreCase -> ignoreCase]@
   Replace[{s_Symbol :> SymbolName@s, 
      e : Except[_String] :> ToString[e]}]@HoldForm@searchIn, 
  HoldAllComplete]
```

Example usage:

```
MarginQ = StringRepresentationContainsQ["margin"]
FilterRules[AbsoluteOptions[EvaluationCell[]], _?(MarginQ)]
```

Results:

```
{CellFrameLabelMargins -> 6, CellFrameMargins -> 8, 
 CellLabelMargins -> {{12, 0}, {2, 0}}, 
 CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {5, 8}}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 WindowMargins -> {{84, 548}, {16, 84}}}
```

For the OP's original post, just replace `StringContainsQ` with `StringMatchQ` or `StringStartsQ`...