# Select nested lists based on string pattern

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to select nested lists out of a master list based on certain string pattern as in the following example:

```
lis = {{a, b, c, d}, {xy, y, z, w}, {e, f, g, h}, {xz, f, g, h}};
```

I would like to create a list with all nested lists starting with `x*` in the fist position.

I tried the following functions:

```
Cases[lis, {q_, r__} /; StringMatchQ[q, "x*"] -> {q, r}]
```

or

```
Select[lis2, First[#] == x &]
```

Both do not work.

Does anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Are those strings in `lis` or you just want to use string patterns for symbols?

Comment: For the latter case I'd say it is a duplicate: [Pattern matching multiple symbols names and powers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75294/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the symbol's name and match for that:

```
Cases[lis, {q_, r__} /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[q], "x*"] -> {q, r}]
(* {{xy, y, z, w}, {xz, f, g, h}} *)
```

or using `Select`:

```
Select[lis, First@Characters[SymbolName[First@#]] == "x" &]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. Obviously my question was incorrect. I have a list of all stock indicies available in Mathematica. Some of these entries are obviously no indices Therefore I would like to select only the "complete" entries using "^*" as identifier .

The list looks as follows:

lis = {{"^DYI", "Dynamic Market Intellidex Index", "AMEX", "Dynamic Market \
Intellidex Index"}, {FinancialData["^EBT-TC", "Symbol"], 
{"^EEV-NV", "Ishares Msci Emerging Markets I", "AMEX", \
"Ishares Msci Emerging Markets I"}}

Any idea?

Thanks Phadreus

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. I missed the String definition of the variable q_String. Here my final function: 
Cases[lis, {q_String, r__} /; StringMatchQ[q, "^*"] -> {q,
    r}]

Comment: At least I pointed you in the right direction. :)

Comment: @Phadreus: And, I hope, my answer is actually an answer to your original question. If so, would you mind marking it as such?