# Selecting elements from lists based on string pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"abc", 1, 2}, {"cde", 3, 4}, {"fgbc", 5, 6}}
```

I would like to select list items that have first elements that end in the string "bc" to give:

```
res = {{1,2},{5,6}}
```

This is a variant on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76827/select-nested-lists-based-on-string-pattern) which has to do with strings only.  Thank you as always for suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Pick[lis[[All, 2 ;;]], StringEndsQ[lis[[All, 1]], "bc"]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {5, 6}}

Also

```
f[{_String?(StringEndsQ["bc"]), x__}] := {x}
f[_] := Sequence[]
f /@ lis
```

> {{1, 2}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 7):

```
lis = {{"abc", 1, 2}, {"cde", 3, 4}, {"fgbc", 5, 6}};
```

Using [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[lis, {_?(StringTake[#, -2] == "bc" &), x_, y_} :> {x, y}, 
  Infinity]

(* {{1, 2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

or

```
Rest /@ Cases[lis, {_?(StringTake[#, -2] == "bc" &), __}, Infinity]

(* {{1, 2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Or using [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html)

```
Rest /@ Select[lis, StringTake[#[[1]], -2] == "bc" &]

(* {{1, 2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Or using [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
Rest /@ DeleteCases[lis, {_?(StringTake[#, -2] != "bc" &), __}, 
  Infinity]

(* {{1, 2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

This uses string matching on the first element of each sublist and then discards the first element from the matches.

```
lis = {{"abc", 1, 2}, {"cde", 3, 4}, {"fgbc", 5, 6}};
Rest/@Select[lis,StringMatchQ[First[#],RegularExpression["\\w*bc"]]&]

(* {{1, 2}, {5, 6}} *)
```

You may need to adjust the pattern given to `RegularExpression` if your strings do not all begin with word characters.

Answer (score 3):

This works too:

```
If[StringEndsQ[#1, "bc"], {##2}, Nothing] & @@ # & /@ lis
```

since list elements that are `Nothing` are automatically stripped from the sequence.

Comment: Why use  `(f@@ #) & /@lis` instead of `f@@@lis`?

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = {{"abc", 1, 2}, {"cde", 3, 4}, {"fgbc", 5, 6}};
```

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
SubsetMap[StringEndsQ[#, "bc"] &, lis, {All, 1}] // 
  Select[ContainsNone[{False}]] // Map[Rest]
```

---

**Using `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
Scan[If[StringEndsQ[First@#, "bc"], Sow[Rest@#], Nothing] &, lis] // 
   Reap // Last // First
```

---

*Result*

> {{1, 2}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = {{"abc", 1, 2}, {"cde", 3, 4}, {"fgbc", 5, 6}};

Values @ KeySelect[StringEndsQ @ "bc"] @ MapApply[# -> {##2} &] @ lis
```

{{1, 2}, {5, 6}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases` and `StringEndsQ`:

```
Cases[lis, {y_ /; StringEndsQ[y, "bc"], x__} :> {x}]

(*{{1, 2}, {5, 6}}*)
```