# How to iterate through a list of rules?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Let's consider I have a list of rules:

```
{Aa -> 1/2, Av -> 2/5, Bx -> 3/7, Ce -> 4/9, ...}
```

I want to find all keys that contain the letter "A" and change their values to expressions. This means to have as a result:

```
***Some code here...***
{Aa -> ToExpression[1/2], Av -> ToExpression[2/5], Bx->3/7, Ce->4/9, ...}
```

Comment: if you are afraid of evaluation of `Aa`.., related: [75294](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75294/5478)

Comment: Your question implies that some or all the keys and values in your list are strings, but in your post they all look like symbols or rational numbers. Please reformat your example to make the strings explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
Clear[f];
f[key_ -> val_] := key -> If[
   StringMatchQ[ToString@key, ___ ~~ "A" | "a" ~~ ___], q@val, val]
```

then

```
f /@ {Aa->1/2, Av->2/5, Bx->3/7, Ce->4/9}
(* {Aa -> q[1/2], Av -> q[2/5], Bx -> 3/7, Ce -> 4/9} *)
```

If you have v10, and your data is in an `Association`, you use `AssociationMap`, instead:

```
AssociationMap[f, <|Aa->1/2, Av->2/5, Bx->3/7, Ce->4/9|>
(* <|Aa -> q[1/2], Av -> q[2/5], Bx -> 3/7, Ce -> 4/9|> *)
```

---

An alternative to `StringMatchQ`, which I usually forget about, is `StringFreeQ` which simplifies the implementation:

```
Clear[g];
g[key_ -> val_] := key -> If[StringFreeQ[ToString@key, "A" | "a"], val, q@val]
```

Comment: There is `StringFreeQ`.

Comment: @Kuba yep. That's one I usually forget exists.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on the theme:

```
test = {Aa -> "1/2", Av -> "2/5", Bx -> "3/7", Ce -> "4/9"};

test /. (key_ /; 
     StringMatchQ[ToString[key], ___ ~~ "a" | "A" ~~ ___] -> 
    val_) :> (key -> ToExpression[val])

(*{Aa -> 1/2, Av -> 2/5, Bx -> "3/7", Ce -> "4/9"}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
    as = <|"Aa" -> "1/2", "Av" -> "2/5", "Ca" -> "3/4", "Bx" -> "3/7", 
   "Ce" -> "4/9"|>;
ks = KeySelect[as, 
   Characters[#][[1]] == "A" || Characters[#][[2]] == "a" &];
op = Map[ToExpression, ks, 2];

Merge[{Association[Complement[Normal[as], Normal[ks]]], op}, Total]
```

yielding

```
    (*  <|"Bx" -> "3/7", "Ce" -> "4/9", "Aa" -> 1/2, "Av" -> 2/5, "Ca" -> 3/4|
 >   *)
```