# Replacing symbol

Tags: replacement

How can I relpace in a list like this a `Symbol` by `{}`:

```
{x$1273, 14, x$1275}, {25, 33}, {x$1274}}
```

I would like to get:

```
{{}, 14, {}}, {25, 33}, {{}}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75294/121

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with level spec `{-1}`:

```
Replace[{{x$1273, 14, x$1275}, {25, 33}, {x$1274}}, _Symbol -> {}, {-1}]
```

> {{{}, 14, {}}, {25, 33}, {{}}}

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to worry about levels, you can use

```
{{x$1273, 14, x$1275}, {25, 33}, {x$1274}}/. Except[List, _Symbol] -> {}
```

> `{{{}, 14, {}}, {25, 33}, {{}}}`