# Select variable and its derivatives

Tags: expression-manipulation

A simple question:

I have this equation:

```
eq1=Derivative[0, 1][T1][x, t] - Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2 - 
 T0[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][T0][x, t] - Derivative[2, 0][T1][x, t] == 0;
```

I want only to select terms that contain T0 or its derivatives only, that is:

```
-Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2 - T0[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][T0][x, t]
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: `DeleteCases[eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract, _?(FreeQ[#,T0]&]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 there is a parenthesis missing after the & symbol. Great answer though. More elegant than mine!

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Gedanken Mathematica, you know the one that's basically a keyboard without a kernel. Hard to catch those typos.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can use the `Collect`command in the following manner

```
eq1 =  Derivative[0, 1][T1][x, t] - 
       Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2 - 
       T0[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][T0][x, t] - 
       Derivative[2, 0][T1][x, t]; 
       (Coefficient[#1, {T0[x, t], Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, 
       t], Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2}] & )[eq1]
```

This is telling you the coefficient in front of `T0[x, t]` and so on.

Comment: Could you take a look at [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951) and edit your code for readability?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, that's a very good point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Block[{T1, Equal = Plus}, SetAttributes[T1, Constant]; eq1]
```

> ```
> -Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2 - T0[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][T0][x, t]
> ```

Or (thanks to Mr. Wizard [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75295/46490))

```
eq1 /. {s_Symbol /; StringMatchQ[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s], "T" ~~ Except["0"]] -> 0, Equal -> Plus}
```

> ```
> -Derivative[1, 0][T0][x, t]^2 - T0[x, t]*Derivative[2, 0][T0][x, t]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

While the structural operation

```
DeleteCases[eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract, _?(FreeQ[#,T0]&)]
```

works, I prefer using an algebraic approach on a algebraic problem.

```
vars = Select[Not@*FreeQ[T0]]@Variables[eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract];
coeffs = CoefficientArrays[eq1 /. Equal -> Subtract, vars];
Fold[#2 + #1.vars &, Reverse@ReplacePart[coeffs, 1 -> 0]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The structural approach relies on the equation being in a particular form, a flat sum of terms, which does not always happend. The algebraic approach does not. However, `CoefficientArrays` does rely on it being a polynomial in the variables `vars`.